# CreateViews and assigning values to two OneToOneFields

Tags: django

I am trying to set the value of two OneToOne fields on save in a CreateView.

Here are the two models (each living in separate apps).

CompanyProfile app Models.py:

```
class CompanyProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

CompanyData app Models.py:

```
class CompanyData(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    companyprofile = models.OneToOneField(CompanyProfile)
    num_cust = models.FloatField()
```

I would like to set user and companyprofile using the CreateView. I can set the user with form_valid code below.

CompanyData CreateView:

```
class CompanyDataCreateView(generic.CreateView):

    model = models.CompanyData
    fields = ['num_cust']
    template_name = 'company_data/companydata_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.user = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(CompanyDataCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

**Question: How do I also set CompanyProfile to that user's companyprofile at the same time?** Is there a way to do this in form_valid before the save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you already have the `CompanyProfile` created for the user.

So if `CompanyProfile` lives in a separate app, import it.

`from yourproject.companyprofileapp.models import CompanyProfile`

Then run a query on the CompanyProfile objects for one that matches the user making the request.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user
    self.object.companyprofile = CompanyProfile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
    self.object.save()
    return super(CompanyDataCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: This worked! So happy right now. Thank you. I'm a bit of a Django noob and have plenty to learn about querysets, etc. Thanks for the help.

Comment: More than happy to help. I learned a lot of my Django from this site, that's for sure!